# Is this php login system secure /

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I created blog by php and MySQL ,inside this blog there are admin area
in admin area only admin can access
for doing that I did if statement :

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['user']['username'])) {
    header('location: login/');
}
?>
```

the question is :

> is this source or not if not give me one that makes the admin area only
> for admins

Thanks

Comment: have you tried this?

Comment: where/how do you check for the user-type 'admin'?

Comment: This is secure but make the checks role wise instead of seesion key wise as a better design. Also, make sure the PHPSESSID cookie has httponly flag checked (along with HTTPS when you go live)

Comment: Really you should have a die(); command after the header command, to prevent anything accidentally leaking back the client (even if the browser wouldn't normally display it)

Comment: Other than that we can't comment on your overall security, there's far too little information. (And even then, staring at the code is no substitute for rigorous testing)

Comment: I didn't check the role because I only have admin accounts in the DB  @berend

Comment: yeah, I tried it @lagbox

Comment: it is secure if you have only admin account. But even if you have only admin role, it is better to make it user-role-permission system. And check the role and permission in separated code lets call it routing controller. So if user have the right to access this functionality the routing controller will allow it else if user is authenticated but not authorized, the controller should return unauthorized access error. If the user is not authenticated then redirect to login form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one working on my system

```
session_start(); //Start the session
define(ADMIN,$_SESSION['name']); //Get the user name from the previously registered super global variable
if(!session_is_registered("admin")){ //If session not registered
header("location:login.php"); // Redirect to login.php page
}
else //Continue to current page
header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
```

Second One

```
<?php 
if($_SESSION['username'] == 'admin'){ ?>
  <a href='administration.php'>Administration Panel</a> 
<?php } ?>
```